# add a label to a plot with seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn

I did a plot using seaborn,
Here is my pltt  [image]
I would like to add a label for each line.
Can you help me please?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates


from matplotlib import style
import pandas as pd
%pylab inline
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style('darkgrid')
import io
style.use('ggplot')
from datetime import datetime
import time
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8), dpi=100)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
x1 = pd.to_datetime(df_no_missing.TIMESTAMP, format="%h:%m")
y1 = df_no_missing.P_ACT_KW
y3 = df_no_missing.P_SOUSCR
yearFmt = mdates.DateFormatter("%H:%M:%S")
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(yearFmt)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

ax1.plot(x, y1, 'g-')
ax2.plot(x, y2, 'b-')
ax1.plot(x, y3, 'r-')
ax1.set_xlabel('temps')
ax1.set_ylabel('puissance', color='g')
ax2.set_ylabel('dépassement', color='b')
plt.ylim(plt.ylim()[0], 1.0)
plt.show()
```

Thank you in advance
**EDIT**

I try like you mention :

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 5), dpi=100)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
x1 = pd.to_datetime(df_no_missing.TIMESTAMP, format="%h:%m")
y1 = df_no_missing.P_ACT_KW
y3 = df_no_missing.P_SOUSCR
yearFmt = mdates.DateFormatter("%H:%M:%S")
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(yearFmt)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.plot(x, y1, 'g-', label='label 1')
ax2.plot(x, y2, 'b-', label='label 2')
ax1.plot(x, y3, 'r-', label='label 3')
ax1.plot(0, 0, 'b-', label='label 2')
ax.legend(loc=0)             # add legend in top right corner
ax.grid()                    # show grid lines
ax1.set_xlabel('temps')
ax1.set_ylabel('puissance', color='g')
ax2.set_ylabel('dépassement', color='b')
plt.ylim(plt.ylim()[0], 1.0)
plt.show()
```

But I got this error :

> ```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py
> ```
>
> in **call**(self, obj)
>           337                 pass
>           338             else:
>       --> 339                 return printer(obj)
>           340             # Finally look for special method names
>           341             method = _safe_get_formatter_method(obj, self.print_method)
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py
> ```
>
> in (fig)
>           226 
>           227     if 'png' in formats:
>       --> 228         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: print_figure(fig, 'png', **kwargs))
>           229     if 'retina' in formats or 'png2x' in formats:
>           230         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: retina_figure(fig, **kwargs))
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py
> ```
>
> in print_figure(fig, fmt, bbox_inches, **kwargs)
>           117 
>           118     bytes_io = BytesIO()
>       --> 119     fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)
>           120     data = bytes_io.getvalue()
>           121     if fmt == 'svg':
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py
> ```
>
> in print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor,
>   orientation, format, **kwargs)
>          2178                     orientation=orientation,
>          2179                     dryrun=True,
>       -> 2180                     **kwargs)
>          2181                 renderer = self.figure._cachedRenderer
>          2182                 bbox_inches = self.figure.get_tightbbox(renderer)
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py
> ```
>
> in print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs)
>           525 
>           526     def print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs):
>       --> 527         FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
>           528         renderer = self.get_renderer()
>           529         original_dpi = renderer.dpi
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py
> ```
>
> in draw(self)
>           472 
>           473         try:
>       --> 474             self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
>           475         finally:
>           476             RendererAgg.lock.release()
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py
> ```
>
> in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
>            59     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
>            60         before(artist, renderer)
>       ---> 61         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
>            62         after(artist, renderer)
>            63
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py
> ```
>
> in draw(self, renderer)
>          1157         dsu.sort(key=itemgetter(0))
>          1158         for zorder, a, func, args in dsu:
>       -> 1159             func(*args)
>          1160 
>          1161         renderer.close_group('figure')
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py
> ```
>
> in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
>            59     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
>            60         before(artist, renderer)
>       ---> 61         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
>            62         after(artist, renderer)
>            63
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py
> ```
>
> in draw(self, renderer, inframe)
>          2322 
>          2323         for zorder, a in dsu:
>       -> 2324             a.draw(renderer)
>          2325 
>          2326         renderer.close_group('axes')
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py
> ```
>
> in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
>            59     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
>            60         before(artist, renderer)
>       ---> 61         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
>            62         after(artist, renderer)
>            63
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py
> ```
>
> in draw(self, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
>          1104         renderer.open_group(**name**)
>          1105 
>       -> 1106         ticks_to_draw = self._update_ticks(renderer)
>          1107         ticklabelBoxes, ticklabelBoxes2 = self._get_tick_bboxes(ticks_to_draw,
>          1108                                                                 renderer)
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py
> ```
>
> in _update_ticks(self, renderer)
>           947 
>           948         interval = self.get_view_interval()
>       --> 949         tick_tups = [t for t in self.iter_ticks()]
>           950         if self._smart_bounds:
>           951             # handle inverted limits
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py
> ```
>
> in (.0)
>           947 
>           948         interval = self.get_view_interval()
>       --> 949         tick_tups = [t for t in self.iter_ticks()]
>           950         if self._smart_bounds:
>           951             # handle inverted limits
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py
> ```
>
> in iter_ticks(self)
>           890         Iterate through all of the major and minor ticks.
>           891         """
>       --> 892         majorLocs = self.major.locator()
>           893         majorTicks = self.get_major_ticks(len(majorLocs))
>           894         self.major.formatter.set_locs(majorLocs)
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py
> ```
>
> in **call**(self)
>          1004     def **call**(self):
>          1005         'Return the locations of the ticks'
>       -> 1006         self.refresh()
>          1007         return self._locator()
>          1008
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py
> ```
>
> in refresh(self)
>          1024     def refresh(self):
>          1025         'Refresh internal information based on current limits.'
>       -> 1026         dmin, dmax = self.viewlim_to_dt()
>          1027         self._locator = self.get_locator(dmin, dmax)
>          1028
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py
> ```
>
> in viewlim_to_dt(self)
>           768             vmin, vmax = vmax, vmin
>           769 
>       --> 770         return num2date(vmin, self.tz), num2date(vmax, self.tz)
>           771 
>           772     def _get_unit(self):
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py
> ```
>
> in num2date(x, tz)
>           417         tz = _get_rc_timezone()
>           418     if not cbook.iterable(x):
>       --> 419         return _from_ordinalf(x, tz)
>           420     else:
>           421         x = np.asarray(x)
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py
> ```
>
> in _from_ordinalf(x, tz)
>           269 
>           270     ix = int(x)
>       --> 271     dt = datetime.datetime.fromordinal(ix).replace(tzinfo=UTC)
>           272 
>           273     remainder = float(x) - ix
>
> ```
> ValueError: ordinal must be >= 1
>
>
>
>
>
> <matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x1d3b041a400>
> ```

```
 print (df_no_missing.head())
```

> ```
>               TIMESTAMP  P_ACT_KW PERIODE_TARIF  P_SOUSCR       SITE  \
> 145 2015-08-01 23:10:00     248.0            HC     425.0  ST GEREON   
> 146 2015-08-01 23:20:00     244.0            HC     425.0  ST GEREON   
> 147 2015-08-01 23:30:00     243.0            HC     425.0  ST GEREON   
> 148 2015-08-01 23:40:00     238.0            HC     425.0  ST GEREON   
> 149 2015-08-01 23:50:00     234.0            HC     425.0  ST GEREON   
>
>           TARIF  depassement        date      time  
> 145  TURPE_HTA5          0.0  2015-08-01  23:10:00  
> 146  TURPE_HTA5          0.0  2015-08-01  23:20:00  
> 147  TURPE_HTA5          0.0  2015-08-01  23:30:00  
> 148  TURPE_HTA5          0.0  2015-08-01  23:40:00  
> 149  TURPE_HTA5          0.0  2015-08-01  23:50:00
> ```

Comment: Did you mean `legend` instead of `label` by any chance?

Comment: @NickilMaveli thank you for your reply :: for example like in the last plot in this tutorial : https://bespokeblog.wordpress.com/2011/07/07/basic-data-plotting-with-matplotlib-part-2-lines-points-formatting/    (for circle and square)

Comment: Learn to create a [mcve]. Your question contains a lot of unnecessary code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the `label` names to each subplot axis and use `plt.legend` to add the appropriate legends to the center right corner.

```
fig = sns.plt.figure(figsize=(12, 5), dpi=100)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
x1 = pd.to_datetime(df_no_missing.TIMESTAMP)
y1 = df_no_missing.P_ACT_KW
y2 = df_no_missing.depassement
y3 = df_no_missing.P_SOUSCR
yearFmt = mdates.DateFormatter("%H:%M:%S")
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(yearFmt)
ax1.plot(x1, y1, 'g-', label='p_act_kw')
ax1.plot(x1, y3, 'r-', label='p_souscr')
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(x1, y2, 'b-', label='depassement')
h1, l1 = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()
h2, l2 = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax1.legend(h1+h2, l1+l2, loc='center right')
ax1.set_xlabel('temps')
ax1.set_ylabel('puissance', color='g')
ax2.set_ylabel('dépassement', color='b')
sns.plt.ylim(plt.ylim()[0], 1.0)
sns.plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: No, I edit my first post to explain you what kind of error I've got. thank you

Comment: I've changed the arguments slightly. See, if that works.

Comment: No, another error : "ValueError: ordinal must be >= 1"

Comment: same mistake "ValueError: ordinal must be >= 1"

Comment: I see that there is no solution for this problem :/

Comment: If that could be possible, could you do `print df_no_missing.head()` and attach the output of the 3 columns?

Comment: You didn't mention what `y2` equals.

Comment: Ah ok I add to the code :::     y2 = df_no_missing.depassement